# fixed column in footable

Tags: jquery, html, footable

I created an HTML table using the Footable plugin. But I want the first column of this table to be fixed and the rest of the columns are scrolled horizontally.
How can I implement this with the footable plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it, check answer on same issue(almost the same) as you have asked: https://github.com/fooplugins/FooTable/issues/674

Footable gives you possibility only to manipulate with data.

**UPDATE:**

Next code shows you how to add manually classes to table, I think this is only why to do this, by your own.

```
 jQuery("#myTable").footable({
        on: {
            "ready.ft.table": markTask,
            "after.ft.paging": markTask
        },
        paging: {
            enabled: true,
            limit: 25
        },
        filtering: {
            enabled: true,
        },
        columns: columns,
        rows: rows
});


function markTask(ev, ft) {
    ft.$el
        .find("span.danger")
        .parents("tr")
        .addClass("bg-danger");
}
```

Comment: my question is about fixed and sticky column. the issue is about fixed height and width, and a scroller which can scroll the table rows when data is exceeded by a limit.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but there is no given option to do that, most thing like that you need to manipulate at your own, for example it is not possible to filter arrays, so I've exchanged footable function for query.
There is maybe the way if you add to table scroll option by your own,

Comment: @VickieJack see the update, you can try do it like this.